# Webconfig transform not working when publish package due to *.SetParameters.xml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, azure-web-app-service, web.config-transform

How can I avoid these settings when i package my web app.

I can see following entries are added and I have no idea from where these are coming I want to stop them here.

```
2>Adding declared parameter 'IIS Web Application Name'.
2>Adding declared parameter 'AD_APPIDUri'.
2>Adding declared parameter 'AD_MetadataUrl'.
2>Adding declared parameter 'AD_RealmAppSetting'.
2>Adding declared parameter 'AD_AudienceUriAppSetting'.
2>Adding declared parameter 'AD_Domain'.
2>Adding declared parameter 'AD_Issuer'.
```

I have read docs about SetParameters.xml and parameters.xml files, there was no parameters.xml under my solution files I added an empty one myself but still I can still see the following actions. These actions are messing my *project*.SetParameters.xml which is leading to incorrect webconfig transforms when I publish it.

do note that transform preview is showing me what I really wanted but some publishing package turns it into a mess.

I'm using VS2015 and ASP.NET MVC 5 web project

Answer (score 0):

When you build and package a web application, the Web Publishing Pipeline will automatically parameterize these things:

1. The destination IIS web application path and name.
2. Any connection strings in your web.config file.
3. Connection strings for any databases you add to the Package/Publish SQL tab in the project property pages.

'IIS Web Application Name' is automatically add to parameters collection. For other AD parameters, please check your configuration files, have you define them in connectionStrings section? If yes, they also will be automatically added to package parameters collection. To avoid adding these parameters, you could move them to appSettings section.

> I don't want it to be added automatically

To disable the automatically connection string parameters, you could use msbuild.exe to deploy your web application and add [/p:AutoParameterizationWebconfigConnectionstrings=False] parameter to msbuild command. Sample command below is for your reference.

```
msbuild WebApplication1.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=yourProfileName /p:AutoParameterizationWebconfigConnectionstrings=False
```

Comment: that is the behaviour that I've explained too. I don't want it to be added automatically